# Using loadModel in viewer to load .gltf models

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I am trying to use GuiViewer3D in Forge Viewer to load local .gltf file using loadModel() function. Is that even possible or do I need to convert it to .SVF every time? I have noticed that you can also supply a FileLoader. Is there any FileLoader for .gltf files?

[This is the error I get in the viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tj7GA.png)

[This is the error inside js console in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MX9xK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Forge Viewer has (or at least had) an **experimental** support for loading glTF files directly but it looks like that feature is broken at the moment. I used to be able to load glTF files using the `loadModel` method but when I try loading a sample file (tried both glTF 1.0 or glTF 2.0) today with Forge Viewer version 7.*, I get the same error as you.

Coincidentally I have been recently notified by the viewer engineering team about their plan to add **official** support for loading glTF 2.0 files. I'm planning on blogging about the feature on https://forge.autodesk.com/blog as soon as it's available, so please stay tuned!